# How to run/create multiple instances/profiles of Opera 12/15 under only one Installation (at the same time)?

Tags: opera

Asus Laptop
Windows 8
32-bit

1.) How to run/create multiple instances/profiles of Opera 12/15 under only one Installation (at the same time)?

2.) Also, is this also possible in StandAlone installation, or do I need to make multiple copies of StandAlone installation in different folders inside USB drives?

Comment: **Q2:** If you are on a standalone Opera 12 or 15, then yes, you need a separate Opera folder for each instance. As you know, each Opera installation folder will have one profile folder. You can't switch profiles as easily like Chrome can

Comment: **Q1:** You can't use multiple profiles under one normal installation (only workaround is to use multiple standalone installations as you know). What I do is to copy+rename the profile folder name under AppData if I need a second test profile

Comment: @ Nixda: It seems like your 2 answers were both referring to StandAlone install, well, thanks for your answers. But how about the Full Install (under C: Program Files), is there a way wherein I could be able to run multiple profiles or multiple instances of Opera running simultaneously?

Comment: Ah, I see, I overlooked the *simultaneously* fact. Simultaneous running of one opera installation under different profiles is not possible. May I ask why you need them running at the same time?

Comment: @ Nixda: I have 11 B2B personal acconunts used for searching online open bids both for work purposes and freelance works, and also 7 yahoo accounts from different categories I need to be logged in simultaneously. Previously, I just logout-login, logout-login from one account to another continuously every 5 or 10 minutes.

Comment: Fordis, if your intent is simply to log in to websites as multiple users, you can do all of that in one instance of Opera - simply open a new private tab for each case, and they won't share session details with any of the other tabs.

Comment: This is an example for the XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem.:)  Aaamos' solution is the way to go